# What does "error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths." or "error: use of undeclared identifier 'sum'" means in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I've been working on a program. Basically it's like this:

```c
    // CODE A
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int a (string b)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(b); i < n; i++)
        {
            // Something
            sum += number
        }
        return sum;
    }
    ------------------------------------------------------
    // CODE B
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int a (string b)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(b); i < n; i++)
        {
            // Something
            sum += number
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

So when I ran code A, it gave me this error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'sum' [Line 8]

So my initiative was to put the return sum inside the for loop (Like Code B) and gave me an error of:

> error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths. [Line 7]

I didn't understand why exactly is this.

Comment: I cannot see where 'n' is declared either.  Moving the return to inside the loop does not seem sane.  Wfhy not just declare the vars that the compiler is moaning about?

Comment: 'use of undeclared identifier', means that you're trying to use an 'undeclared' identifier, just as the error message said. How about declaring an identifier called 'sum'? And, what good is a loop for, if you exit it in the first run (return statement in the loop).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to sort out some terms: You did not run your program. Instead you only tried to compile it which failed. You cannot run your program before you successfully compiled it. The errors during compilation are very different from errors at runtime.

Comment: You use that `string` type which does not exist in C. If you are doing that CS50 course which uses that weird type, you should tell us. There is a tag that can be added to your question.

Comment: Hello @MartinJames n was declared inside the for loop arguments. Also i already declared sum inside of the for loop. There was my confusion.

Comment: Hi @Gerhardh yea, sorry about that i forgot to mention that what i meant was compiling and i used cs50 header too.

Comment: @Maple06 so it is, my apologies.  Mebbe I have not had enough coffee yet:)

Comment: That is another important thing: You are expected to show code that is complete enough to reproduce the problem. (And as short as possible) See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details. Otherwise we are discussing totally different programs which is not very useful.

Comment: Marting James probably wanted to ask where `number` is defined.

Comment: @MartinJames No no, my apologies. I was the one who didn't type that sum was already defined.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry about all of that. I've edited my question there.

Comment: No need to appologize. Just understand that this is important and keep that in mind next time.

Comment: And finally: Please do never ever edit your code after comments and answers have been provided in a way that invalidates them. If you fix the error that was the very reason of the question, the whole question gets useless. If you add a definition of `sum` you cannot get that error message you mentioned.

Comment: @Gerhardh I already did define sum in the first place, my confusion was I don't know why this gave me the undeclared error even though I defined sum :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error basically means that you have *not* declared `sum` in a way such that the function `a` can find `sum`. One option is to define `sum` (and initialize it to `0`) just before the loop starts: `int sum = 0;`.

In `CODE B`, the function returns an `int`. The compiler is saying that your function does not specify a `return` statement if the `for` loop is never executed (because the condition fails for the first time in some cases).

Moreover, in `CODE B`, even if the loop executes, it does so just once because of the `return` statement.

Perhaps you want to do this:

```
    int a (string b)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(b); i < n; i++)
        {
            // Something
            sum += number; // Assuming number is initialized
        }
        return sum; // This returns `sum` to the calling function
    }
```

You could catch the return value of the function by doing: `int x = a(some_string_argument);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I already define sum before the loop actually. so that was my confusion. Also in code B i am just going to return an integer to put the return value in main. What should i do then? sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

Just add following lines in ExUserFacingNotificationsPermissionsRequester.m in case of react-native/Expo ejected react native

```
- (NSNumber *)authorizationStatusToEnum:(UNAuthorizationStatus)status
{
  switch (status) {
    case UNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
      return @(0);
    case UNAuthorizationStatusDenied:
      return @(1);
    case UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
      return @(2);
    case UNAuthorizationStatusProvisional:
      return @(3);
+    default:
+        return @(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you mean to post this on some other question?